# MATLAB SIMULINK implementing a discrete increment/decrement counter?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, simulink

I have a signal which will be either 1,0 or -1 for a discrete time interval (say 10s) then change depending on other parameters. I want a counter to keep a running count of an Initial Value modified by the input signal.

example:

t0->t1, input=1, output=initialvalue+1

t1->t2, input=0, output=initialvalue+1

t2->t3, input=1, output=(initialvalue+1)+1

t3->t4, input=-1, output=((initialvalue+1)+1)-1

etc. Ideally I would want this to work for input being any integer but I'll take what I can get...

There's a counter block but it only counts up or down, not both. I tried using edge detection but I'm not sure how to implement the discrete counter on which it operates. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Is t0 t1 etc your rate at which the block equates or do you expect it to count only when the input signal changes? For three cycles inputting 1 1 1, what signal do you expect at the end?